# RGB composite of Landsat 8 bands not plotting correctly (Python, GDAL)

Tags: python, gdal, remote-sensing, numpy, landsat-8

I am trying to create a natural color (RGB) image from Landsat 8 data (11 bands). Bands 4, 3, 2, correspond to red, green, blue respectively. When I stack them, however, the images i am getting are not correct. I suspect the issue is with my `astype()` but I am not sure what 'type' I need.

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal, gdal_array

red = gdal.Open(r'/Users/myfiles/Satelite/LC08_L1TP/LC08_L1TP_039037_20130616_20170309_01_T1/LC08_L1TP_039037_20130616_20170309_01_T1_B4.TIF')
green = gdal.Open(r'/Users/myfiles/Satelite/LC08_L1TP/LC08_L1TP_039037_20130616_20170309_01_T1/LC08_L1TP_039037_20130616_20170309_01_T1_B3.TIF')
blue = gdal.Open(r'/Users/myfiles/Satelite/LC08_L1TP/LC08_L1TP_039037_20130616_20170309_01_T1/LC08_L1TP_039037_20130616_20170309_01_T1_B2.TIF')

destination = r'/Users/myfiles/Satelite/rgb.tif'


red_band = red.ReadAsArray()
green_band = green.ReadAsArray()
blue_band = blue.ReadAsArray()

rgb = np.array([red_band, green_band, blue_band])
gdal_array.SaveArray(rgb.astype('uint8'), destination, 'GTiff', red)
```

The above code with `astype('uint8')`, which I have seen recommended for others with this issue, produces the following image:

[image: uint8]

using `astype(np.byte)` produces a very similar image. Omitting the `astype()` produces this image:

[image: notype]

which, frankly, is bizarre. I have tried creating an empty `.tif` and writing to it:

```
gtiff_driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')

rgb = gtiff_driver.Create(destination, red.RasterXSize, red.RasterYSize, 3, gdal.GDT_Byte)

rgb.SetProjection(red.GetProjection())
rgb.SetGeoTransform(red.GetGeoTransform())

rgb.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(red_band)
rgb.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(green_band)
rgb.GetRasterBand(3).WriteArray(blue_band)
```

but that returns an all white raster. And using `np.dstack()` returns the exact same image as the first example.

I am not really sure where to go from here, or where I am going wrong. As far as I can tell I am selecting the correct RGB bands. I need the image to maintain its georeference/ would like to automate it for a number of images otherwise I would just do this in photoshop (see last image).

[image: what i want]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `array.astype()` is not applying any stretching or scaling, you need to do that yourself to make the input range of 16-bit values (2^16-1 == max of 65535) fit into an 8-bit integer (2^8-1 == max of 255).  You're getting integer overflow leading to that wonky image, values larger than that 8-bit max are wrapping back around from the minimum.

A quick way could be to do:

`scaled = (rgb * (255 / 65535)).astype(np.uint8)`