# Converting Landsat 8 RGB bands to 8-bit colors

Tags: google-earth-engine, color, landsat-8, google-earth-engine-python-api, rgb

I generated composite images of Landsat 8 SR images using this [Google Earth Engine collection](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C01_T1_SR), and for a machine learning project now I need to transform the RGB bands of these images to 8-bit colors.

I'm using Python, I downloaded my composite images as `.TIFF`, and following some answers to other questions like [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/349268/176237), I tried the following to convert the RGB part of my images to 8-bit colors:

```
#loading packages
import imageio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#reading the image
image=imageio.v3.imread('image_test.tif')

#taking GRB channels from the image, reordering them to RGB, and converting colors to 8-bits
image_rgb=(image[:,:,[3,2,1]]/255).astype('uint8')

plt.imshow(image_rgb)
```

I took the image, kept the RGB bands only (so I can visualize it), and divided by 255 (since original colors are 16-bit) and took away the decimal part to get only integers, but I obtain the following when plotting:

[image]

The `image_test.tif` file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dckqvydt4f51fp0/image_test.tif?dl=0). I also visualized my image using `GEE`, and it should look like this (I used visualization parameters `'min': 0, 'max': 3000, 'gamma': 1.4`):

[image]

How do I correctly convert the color in these images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this would be to export it as an 8-bit image to begin with.

```
image.multiply(0.0001).multiply(256).uint8()
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ac2dc95badf941f035fc3bad12e7fdd0

If that's not an option, you can do it directly in Python, but you don't want to divide by `256`. Instead, multiply with the scale of the image (`0.0001` in [your case](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C01_T1_SR#bands)) to get it between `0` and `1`, then multiply by `256`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I cannot re-export them, but multiplying by the scale and 256 worked perfectly. [Here is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk4RT.png), which is exactly how it should look without the gamma corrections and stuff.